# Software to get FOREX data in CSV format

Tags: data, csv

Could you guys recommend me a software that can:

- Download today's FOREX data only.
- Forex Currencies must contain Peso, Yen, Chinese yuan (Please correct me if I'm wrong), Euro. (If it can be modified, it would be awesome).
- The data must be like `$1 = PHP 51.83` as an example.
- The data can be exported into a CSV file
- The exported file must contain all the data of today's Forex
- Must be user friendly and preferably free

I tried to use TickStory but it's a tad tedious to use because I have to download the data that I want, before exporting them to Excel. I also cannot download today's file, which is one of the important feature that I want.

EDIT:

I might not be clear enough so I thought I need to indicate the exact format of the software that I want to have (or maybe something near this)

Please do take a look at this picture; it came from [Yahoo! Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/currencies/), but I can't export it into CSV file.

[image]